# How to get total amount from all currency in list of map

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of map, you can say like this:

```
 [{id: 2020-09-08 12:28:55.065818, amount: 60.0, currency: MAD},
 {id: 2020-09-08 12:48:31.771243, amount: 10.0, currency: EUR},
 {id: 2020-09-08 12:48:44.270123, amount: 100.0,currency: USD,},
 {id: 2020-09-08 12:50:22.818595, amount: 50.0, currency: USD,}]
```

Actually my map is larger more and more from this and has more attributes anyway.
I'm trying to calculate all amounts to same currency and store him in another map.
The result should be

> [ {currency: MAD , amount:60.0}, {currency: USD, amount:150.0},
> {currency: EUR, amount:10.0}, ]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fold method on your list to do that :

```
var data = [
  {'id': '2020-09-08 12:28:55.065818', 'amount': 60.0, 'currency': 'MAD'},
  {'id': '2020-09-08 12:48:31.771243', 'amount': 10.0, 'currency': 'EUR'},
  {'id': '2020-09-08 12:48:44.270123', 'amount': 100.0, 'currency': 'USD'},
  {'id': '2020-09-08 12:50:22.818595', 'amount': 50.0, 'currency': 'USD'}
];
print(data.fold(0, (previousValue, element) => (element['amount'] as double) + previousValue));
```

Hope it's help